# How to disable security certificate check with Julia's Downloads.jl?

Tags: http, ssl, curl, https, julia

In Python, I can run

```
import requests
url = "https://www.cij.gov.ar/d/sentencia-SGU-afb60c47-0de3-4e3f-869f-ff0d4abcb1a8.pdf"
requests.get(url, verify = False)
```

in order to bypass the missing certificate exception.

However, running `Downloads.download("https://www.cij.gov.ar/d/sentencia-SGU-afb60c47-0de3-4e3f-869f-ff0d4abcb1a8.pdf")` raises `ERROR: Cert verify failed: BADCERT_NOT_TRUSTED while requesting`.

Is there a way to disable the check in Julia as well?

(If the answer involves toggling some environmental variables, I'm looking to doing this within the VSCODE Julia extension, which doesn't always look at the same variables as the regular REPL...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTTP.jl (I use an url which has broken certificate - your example seems to have a valid one):

```
val = HTTP.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/", require_ssl_verification=false)
```

now `val.body` contains all bytes you need and you can save the to file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that server's SSL is low quality, though most browsers take it, and Python apparently does. It has an incomplete chain:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.cij.gov.ar&latest

Perhaps you could install the site's certificates directly on your machine as trusted, so curl does not forbid it. I don't know why curl, which is what download,jl uses, is set to forbid grade B connections though.

Comment: There is no standard or universal 'grading' for TLS. _ssllabs_ was created to test _protocol_ correctness and compatibility: versions, ciphersuites, features like renegotiation (original and 5746) and stapling, flaws and bugs like heartbleed and logjam, etc, and originally the cert wasn't even counted in the grade; Ivan apparently got enough complaints that cert errors now count but only a little, while for things that actually want to communicate securely (including curl without -k/--insecure) certificate validation is vital.